# Xcode 8.3.3: Unable to push to repo using ssh key

Tags: macos, xcode, git

I have my github repo setup with ssh key to access it: pull/push.

With command-line git commands it does flawlessly.

But I can't push with Xcode.

[image]

I don't have any passphrase with my private key.

Whenever I press [OK], I'm getting the same window again and again. No error or something.